# Trying To insert data into swiftdata right after I deleted the model throws an error: IOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

So I'm saving Day Objects using SwiftData.

```
@Model
class Day: Hashable {
    let id : UUID
    let date: Date
    var percentageCompleted: Double
    var completedHabitIDs: Set<UUID>

init(id: UUID, date: Date, percentageCompleted: Double, completedHabitIDs: Set<UUID>) {
    self.id = id
    self.date = date
    self.percentageCompleted = percentageCompleted
    self.completedHabitIDs = completedHabitIDs
    }
}
```

There's a function that deletes all user data

```
// Environment Variables
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var context


private func eraseData() {
    do {
        try context.delete(model: Day.self)
        try context.delete(model: Habit.self)
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        gvm.onlineSync = false
        gvm.currentUser = nil
        onlineSyncToggle = false
        try context.save()
        deleted()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to Erasa Data")
    }
}
```

Right After I call the `eraseData` function, I'm trying to save a dayObject for today because it was just deleting and the app needs a dayObject.

```
 private func saveTodOrDay(day: Day? = nil) -> Day {
        let dayObj = day != nil ? day! : vm.createEmptyDateObj(for: Date())
        context.insert(dayObj)
        return dayObj
    }
```

The Catch block of the `eraseData` doesn't get executed therefore no errors are thrown, the problem is here in the `context.insert(dayObj)` line.

```
Thread 17: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8000000000000008)
```

That's the error I got when i ran in the simulator
Why is that? and how can I fix it?

Comment: That error message doesn’t say much, could you add some more context (code)? Have you debugged the code or turned on core data debug logging?